# Login to OneDrive OS X with School/Company account

Tags: mac-appstore, microsoft

Is there a way to login and access your OneDrive account with the OneDrive application from the Mac Store with your school/company account? At the moment, my credentials are not recognized.

Comment: Does it work if you log in from within the school?

Comment: Unfortunately not. For example with Office 365/Office 2016 for OS X, when I enter my schools mail address in the login to One Drive form, it redirects me to the login page from my university, but the OneDrive for OS X app doesn't.

Comment: So maybe the credentials are just wrong?

Comment: I used the wrong version, I don't exactly know why there are separate versions of one drive, but anyhow I needed OneDrive for Business. Thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know there were two separate versions of OneDrive, one for schools/companies, that is called *OneDrive Business* and one for normal Microsoft Accounts that is just called *OneDrive*. According to [the official homepage](https://onedrive.live.com/about/nl-nl/download/) OneDrive for Business is not available (yet) for OS X. Although as stated [here](http://thenextweb.com/apps/2015/01/29/onedrive-business-cloud-storage-comes-os-x-gets-integrated-onedrive-ios/), it is coming and a [preview version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45519) is available for download now. And fortunately, it works.

> OneDrive for Business is also making its debut on OS X today, in the form of a sync client available as a public preview from the Microsoft Download Center.